# Rotation by $\pi/3$

Tags: linear-transformations

The vector $[4 - 2 \sqrt{3}, 4 + 8 \sqrt{3}]^T$ is the image of a vector $v$ under the linear transformation $F : R^2 \rightarrow R^2,$ which is a linear transformation which first rotates a vector anti-clockwise by $\pi/3$ and then halves the first element of the vector $v.$ Calculate $v.$

What I have tried, as we know the operator that rotates a vector in $R^2$ through a given angle $\theta$ is called a rotation operator in $R^2$ and here 
$F(v) = (v_1 cos \theta - v_2 sin \theta; v_1 sin \theta + v_2 cos \theta)$ and $\theta = \pi/3.$ So $F(v)$ becomes $(\frac{v_1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt3 v_2}{2}; \frac{\sqrt3v_1}{2} + \frac{v_2}{2}).$ Then according to the question halves the first element of the vector $v.$ Hence

$F(v) = (\frac{v_1}{4} - \frac{\sqrt3 v_2}{2}; \frac{\sqrt3v_1}{4} + \frac{v_2}{2}) = [4 - 2 \sqrt{3}, 4 + 8 \sqrt{3}].$ Is it correct? Kindly let me know.

Comment: You haven’t completed the problem. What does $v$ turn out to be?

Comment: It is not correct even as far as you've gone, though the problem is fairly minor: In the middle paragraph, you correctly calculate $F(v)$ in terms of $v_1, v_2$, but when you set it equal to the original vector in the final paragraph, oddly two of the denominators suddenly switch from $2$ to $4$. Correct that, then solve for $v_1, v_2$, and find $v$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes sir, that would be 2 instead of 4. Then we can get 2 equations with 2 unkonwn. So we can find $v_1$ and $v_2.$ But what is the role of "then halves the first element of the vector v".

Comment: Ok sir. I have solved it.

Comment: Sorry - somehow I missed the "then halves" instruction when I made the comment. However, as I assume you have figured out when you solved it, you mistook the order of operations, The final form of $F$ would be $$F(v) = (\frac{v_1}4 - \frac{\sqrt3 v_2}4, \frac{\sqrt3v_1}2 + \frac{v_2}2)$$